# captcha recognition using tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, image-recognition

I'm trying to learn captcha recognition using CNN, there are a example I'm studying that is captcha recognition using tensor flow. But I have some questions about the example.

In this case, using captcha generator, we can get the text and image about captcha

## text, image = gen_captcha_text_and_image()

```
def get_next_batch(batch_size = 128):
    batch_x = np.zeros([batch_size, IMAGE_HEIGHT*IMAGE_WIDTH])
    batch_y = np.zeros([batch_size, MAX_CAPTCHA*CHAR_SET_LEN])


    def wrap_gen_captcha_text_and_image():
        while True:
            text, image = gen_captcha_text_and_image()
            if image.shape == (60, 160, 3):
                return text, image

    for i in range(batch_size):
        text, image = wrap_gen_captcha_text_and_image()
        image = convert2gray(image)

        batch_x[i,:] = image.flatten() / 255
        batch_y[i,:] = text2vec(text)


    return batch_x, batch_y
```

## Training

when computing the recognition accuracy, need batch_x and batch_y

```
def train_crack_captcha_cnn():

    output = crack_captcha_cnn()

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=output, labels=Y))

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)

    predict = tf.reshape(output, [-1, MAX_CAPTCHA, CHAR_SET_LEN])
    max_idx_p = tf.argmax(predict, 2)
    max_idx_l = tf.argmax(tf.reshape(Y, [-1, MAX_CAPTCHA, CHAR_SET_LEN]), 2)
    correct_pred = tf.equal(max_idx_p, max_idx_l)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        step = 0
        while True:
            batch_x, batch_y = get_next_batch(64)
            _, loss_ = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y, keep_prob: 0.75})
            print(step, loss_)


            if step % 100 == 0:
                batch_x_test, batch_y_test = get_next_batch(100)
                acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: batch_x_test, Y: batch_y_test, keep_prob: 1.})
                print(step, acc)
            # when accuracy >80%, save model, finish train
                if acc > 0.8:
                    saver.save(sess, "crack_capcha.model", global_step=step)
                    break
            step += 1
```

the result is

```
6291 0.0297899
6292 0.024521
6293 0.0278097
6294 0.0307284
6295 0.027667
6296 0.026684
6297 0.0264348
6298 0.0280007
6299 0.0298581
6300 0.0278418
6300 0.815
```

**But when I get big training data from internet, not using the captcha generator create.**

```
batch_y[i,:] = text2vec(text)
```

[image]

[image]

## can't get the text in the captcha, batch_y[i,:] is null.

when computing the accuracy
the result is

```
0 0.69474
0 0.0
1 0.66162
2 0.605672
3 0.509237
4 0.367824
5 0.201136
6 0.0657851
7 0.0105976
8 0.000712345
9 2.42625e-05
10 4.68649e-07
11 4.37849e-09
12 1.94186e-11
13 9.17299e-14
14 2.86322e-16
15 6.33826e-19
16 1.34238e-21
17 1.64283e-24
18 4.54483e-27
19 4.26165e-30
20 7.20557e-33
21 4.39262e-35
22 1.08497e-37
23 0.0
24 0.0
25 0.0
...
n  0.0
```

There are no text about captcha, so text2vec() is not useful. Then the accuracy can't be computed...

---

I tried to use training model from captcha generator to identify captcha from web. The result is terrible!

**The following is captcha from captcha generator**
[image]
**convert2gray**
[image]
Training model can identify success!

**However, the captcha from the web**
[image]
**resize the image from (25, 52) to (60, 160)**
[image]
**convert2gray**
[image]

It can't be identify success !